# Why my nested form won't submit data correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Community has_many CommunityTopics
It shows form of CommunityTopics When I access to example.com/shop/WALMART/topic/new
and it create new record after submit.
But all the data I typed won't be saved and all of them become empty:(

My codes are

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
end
```

**models/community.rb**

```
def to_param
  "#{community_name}"
end
```

**community_topics_controller.rb #new**

```
  def new
    @community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id]) 
    @community_topic = @community.community_topics.build 
    @community_topic.user_id = current_user.id 


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @community_topic }
    end
  end
```

**community_topics_controller.rb #create**

```
  def create
    @community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id]) 
    @community_topic = @community.community_topics.build (params[:id]) 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @community_topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to community_topic_path(@community.community_name, @community_topic), notice: 'Community topic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: [@community, @community_topic], status: :created, location: @community_topic }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @community_topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**views/community_topics/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :community_topic, url: community_topic_index_url, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :community_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :community_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :user_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :user_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                community_topic_index_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this line

```
@community_topic = @community.community_topics.build (params[:id])
```

you passed wrong parameter into that. Should be

```
params[:community_topic] :)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfect!! Please let me make sure this. 1st line **@community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id])**  is to select what Community to belong to. Right? and your answer,which is 2nd line exist to make record itself using params that were input in  previous form.  Right?

Comment: Oh, you wrote this line wrong aswel. If you are trying to find the relevant community here, just `@community = Community.find(params[:community_id])` will work. Make sure you change the new action too.

Comment: what if I'm using  **to_param** in Community model? I am using column called 'community_name' as slug. Should I still use **@community = Community.find(params[:community_id])** instead?

Comment: I think I was right. It seems that I have to use **@community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id])** since I was using **to_param**

Comment: oh, ok, sorry i didn't see that.